# For valid probability densities $p(x)$ and $q(x), \int p(x)\ln(q(x))~dx = 0$. Can you catch my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I was trying to solve the following integral by parts, $$ \int p(x)\ln(q(x))dx$$ for valid probability density functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$,

$$ \int p(x)\ln(q(x))dx = \ln(q(x)) - \int\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)}dx,$$ since $p(x)$ is assumed second function in the product and $\int p(x)dx = 1$.
$$ \int p(x)\ln(q(x))dx = \ln(q(x)) - \int\frac{q'(x)}{q(x)}dx = \ln(q(x)) - \ln(q(x)) = 0.$$
Is this wrong even if the limits are assumed to be entire $\mathbb{R}$. I'm sure this is very elementary and I'm missing something very fundamental here.

Comment: I don't understand your by-parts calculation.  In the integral $\int u~dv = uv - \int v~du$, what is your $u$ and what is your $dv$?

Comment: I used the formula - $\int u.v dx = u.[\int v.dx] - \int \frac{du}{dx} [\int vdx ] dx$.

Comment: If I'm right, then the K-L divergence will just reduce to negative entropy. That cannot happen, so I'm definitely wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to specify some bounds here, say $a$ and $b$. Note that assuming the existence of $\ln(q(x))$ requires $q(x)$ to be positive on the interval (while there may be probability densities on the interval that don't have this property, we don't care about them right now).

Let $P$ be an antiderivative of $p$ on $[a,b]$, i.e. a function on $[a,b]$ with $P'(x) = p(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

By integration by parts with "$u$" taken to be $\ln(q(x))$ and "$dv$" taken to be $p(x)$ we have $du = q'(x)/q(x)$ and $v = P(x)$, so
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b p(x) \ln(q(x)) \, dx & = \ln(q(x)) P(x) \Big \vert_a^b - \int_a^b P(x) \frac{q'(x)}{q(x)} \, dx \\
& = \ln(q(b)) P(b) - \ln(q(a)) P(a) - \int_a^b P(x) \frac{q'(x)}{q(x)} \, dx.
\end{align*}
$$
which looks fine to me, but no cancellation takes place.

The issue is that the integration by parts formula requires an antiderivative of $p$, which is a *function*, and which is definitely not the *number* $\int_a^b p(x) \, dx$.  (If this number were an antiderivative of $p$, then $p$ would be constant and not a valid probability distribution.)  The distinction is blurred if you omit bounds everywhere and write $\int p(x) dx$ for both objects.